# Binding to map's ZoomLevel kills binding for other elements

Tags: windows-phone, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1

OK, bizarre issue here.  I have a map, and I am binding to the center and zoom level.  However, binding to the ZoomLevel has odd consequences.

1. If I move the ZoomLevel binding before the Center binding, it kills the Center binding.  Setting the Center in the view model has no effect, and moving the map around does not update the Center property.
2. If I keep it as shown, Center and ZoomLevel bind properly, but the MapItemsControl does not.  When I search, pushpins for the search results do not show up on the map.
3. If I remove the ZoomLevel binding entirely, everything works -- Center binds correctly, and the pushpins show up.  But, I have no programmatic control over the zoom level now.

This has left me completely bewildered.  I have tried changing it to OneWay (I don't really need to know the zoom level in the view model, only set it) but then setting the zoom level in the view model no longer zooms the map, which is bizarre as well.  I can change Center to be one-way and it still recenters the map when changed in the view model.

```
<map:MapControl Grid.Row="0"
    Center="{Binding Path=Center, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ZoomLevel="{Binding Path=ZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
    MapServiceToken="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MapServiceToken}">
    <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResults}">
        <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Background="Red" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" map:MapControl.Location="{Binding Path=Point}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </map:MapItemsControl>
</map:MapControl>
```

**EDIT**: For those interested, initializing the ZoomLevel to a non-zero value in the view model's constructor seems to resolve this.